# What is the heaviest Single Engine Prop Plane that has been flown?

Tags: single-engine

What is the heaviest single engine propeller-driven fixed-wing aircraft that's been produced & actually flown?

- Experimental and one-of-a-kind aircraft count, as long as it has actually flown.
- The maximum takeoff weight, as certified or designed, is the weight that counts (i.e. not merely empty weight, but with payload + fuel at the start of the flight).
- Turboprops count, biplanes count, any timeframe (well, pre-1900 may be hard) and any country, civil or military.

Comment: It's worth noting there are [single propeller aircraft driven by multiple engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linke-Hofmann_R.II). Does that count? And there are [dual contra-rotating propellers driven by dual engines](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33535/3201). Does that count?

Comment: @mins I'd be good with those - the characteristic I'm most interested in is having a single place on the aircraft with prop blades (i.e. on the nose, not on both wings or front+back), so the number of engines spinning the shaft or the presence of the contra-rotating prop aren't my main concerns.

Answer (score 8):

Possible candidates:

- [XF8B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_XF8B) with MTOW 21,681 lbs (9,831 kg).
- [XF-84H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_XF-84H_Thunderscreech)? It's based on an airframe with MTOW of 27,000 lbs (12,247 kg) with a turboprop slapped on the front. Wikipedia claims a MTOW weight of 27,046 lbs (12,268 kg), but it's of questionable providence so I'm hesitant to claim it as fact.
- [Tu-91](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu-91), MTOW 31,747 lb (14,400 kg). XTB2D, 34,760 lb (15,767 kg)
- [Grumman Mauler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_AM_Mauler) - once lifted payload of 10648 pounds of ordinance alone - empty weight listed as 15,257 lb (6,920 kg), gross weight listed as 25,737 lb (11,674 kg) -- but some heavier listed in comments above

Answer (score 4):

The [Douglas XB-42 Mixmaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_XB-42_Mixmaster) had a maximum take of weight of **16,194kg** (35,702lbs). (Note - the later [A variant](https://oldmachinepress.com/2017/08/05/douglas-xb-42-mixmaster-attack-bomber/) had a couple of underwing jets, which took the mtow above 20,000kg.) It was powered by two Allison V-1710 engines each independently connected to one of the contra-rotating propellers. In an emergency, the entire rear assemblage could be explosively jettisoned.

[image: XB-42 Mixmaster]

There is the [Douglas XTB2D Skypirate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_XTB2D_Skypirate) with a maximum take-off weight of **15,767kg** (34,760 lbs).
It had a single Pratt & Whitney XR-4360-8 supercharged 3000hp radial piston engine driving a pair of 14.3-foot diameter, contra-rotaing four-bladed propellers.

[image: Douglas XTB2D Skypirate]
The first U.S. Navy Douglas XTB2D-1 Skypirate prototype ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_XTB2D_Skypirate#/media/File:Douglas_XTB2D-1_landing_c1945.jpg))

Both these planes have contra-rotating propellers. For the largest plane with a *single* propeller, it may be the [Linke-Hofmann R.II](https://www.aviastar.org/air/germany/linke-hoffmann_r-2.php) of 1917, with a gross weight of **12,000kg** (26,455lbs) . It is said to have had the largest propeller ever flown, its four engines turning a single 6.90m (22 ft 7.5 in) diameter two-blade propeller at just 545rpm.

[image: Linke-Hoffman R.II] ([source](https://flyingmachines.ru/Site2/Crafts/Craft30118.htm)) *looks normal until you notice the people*

And... **this one is a bit of a cheat**, but also the **[Boeing JB-17G](https://aerialvisuals.ca/AirframeDossier.php?Serial=23484)** engine test-bed. Since the B-17G had an *empty* weight of around 17,000kg, it comfortably beats the other contenders.
In flight its main engines were shut down, and it was flown with a single engine.

[image: Boeing JB-17G]

Comment: The XB-42 hat **two** Allison 1710 engines mounted in its fuselage.

Comment: @PeterKämpf  true, but the op says "the number of engines spinning the shaft or the presence of the contra-rotating prop aren't my main concerns" so I think it counts!